# Open a password protected EXCEL in wamp using PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel, fopen, password-protection

I have an excel that has a password (When you open it, it asks for a password). I want to open it and save it to a new folder. Supposing that there is no password my script would be :

```
    <?php

    $url = 'http://localhost/1472742721137_Book1.xlsx';
    $destination_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/YOLO/';


        $newfname = $destination_folder .'Book1.xlsx'; //set your file ext

        $file = fopen ($url, "rb");

        if ($file) {
          $newf = fopen ($newfname, "a"); // to overwrite existing file

          if ($newf)
          while(!feof($file)) {
            fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );

          }
        }

        if ($file) {
          fclose($file);
        }

        if ($newf) {
          fclose($newf);
        }

    ?>
```

How can I mention the password of the file in the `fopen` function? It must be only one line that does that.

Otherwise, I will have to use PHPExcel but that is something I want to avoid as it brings me many errors even though I am trying to make it work for a NON protected excel file.

My steps :

a) I downloaded the files and extracted them from github .

b) I then added this script:

```
<?php

include '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$url = '1472742721137_Book1.xlsx';
$destination_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/YOLO/';

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($url);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$workbook = $reader->load($url);
$objWriter->save($destination_folder);

?>
```

c) I am getting this errors :

[image]

**UPD:**

I made the script work finally. Now, all I need is to add the line that will get the password. The file has a password that I need to add in my script in order to open it and then save it (without a password).

[image]

My script :

```
<?php

include '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$url = 'AAAAA.xlsx';
$destination_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/YOLO/';

$fileType=PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($url);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);

$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);   
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($url);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
$objWriter->save($destination_folder.'/output.xlsx');

?>
```

Comment: The file is on the same server as  this very PHP script…? Are you talking about an HTTP Basic Authentication password?

Comment: If it's a local file, then fopen() doesn't care whether a file is protected by an MS Excel password or not

Comment: @Mark Even if it's a *remote* file, `fopen` doesn't know or care about *Excel passwords*… :)

Comment: @deceze - nope, agreed, but the it could be the remote uri that's password protected rather than the file itself

Comment: @Apolo And if this is not about Excel passwords but ".htaccess" passwords: don't use `http://localhost/…`, access the file as *local* file, probably as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/…'`…

Comment: Give us more details. 1) What kind of password are you talking about, there are several possible levels. 2) What error are you experiencing exactly?

Comment: @deceze I added more info and the alternative. Cheers

Comment: First off, get PHPExcel from [github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) not from codeplex.... the codeplex site is 5 years out-of-date, and we' have killed it off long ago if MS (who run codeplex) had let us

Comment: Uhm, am I missing something? `file_put_contents('copy.xlsx', fopen('147….xlsx', 'rb'));`

Comment: Second, PHPExcel cannot open files from a remote server/url, only from the local filesystem; nor will it save to a remote server/url, only to the local filesystem, or a download stream like php://output

Comment: @MarkBaker I downloaded the files from github. I put them in a folder called "Classes" like the documentation said. I am using the script (second one above) and I get this errors :
Undefined variable: objWriter in C:\wamp\www\TREKSE2.php on line 11
Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\TREKSE2.php on line 11

Comment: `$objWriter->save($destination_folder);`..... so where/how are you instantiating `$objWriter`?

Comment: @MarkBaker I made it work
    
    `include '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';`
    
    `$url = 'file.xlsx';`
    `$destination_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/YOLO/';`
    
    `$fileType=PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($url);`
    `$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");`
     
    `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);`   
    `$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($url);`
    
    `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);`
    `$objWriter->save($destination_folder.'/output.xlsx');`

Now, all I need is the line with the password.

Comment: You're using `$fileType=PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($url);` to identify the filetype, so you should really be using that identified filetype rather than instantiating a specific named Reader: `$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);`

Comment: And only use `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);` if you want all styling and formatting to be stripped out from the file

Comment: But there is no password line; PHPExcel will read files that are protected with Microsoft's default password

Comment: @MarkBaker Isn't there a way to add the password of the file in the script then? I updated the question with an image to show you what I mean. Cheers

Comment: @deceze What did you mean before? I did not get it :P 
`contents('copy.xlsx', fopen('147….xlsx', 'rb')`

Comment: `Isn't there a way to add the password of the file in the script then?` I'm afraid not.... I have no idea how to decrypt a spreadsheet file that is entirely encrypted with anything other than the default MS password, so PHPExcel is incapable of doing that

Comment: @MarkBaker So, with PHP it is impossible. I guess it will only work if I use a LOAD DATA INFILE of SQL in my script. Unless there is a way to use VBA in the PHP file.

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE will only work with CSV files, and they cannot be password protected by an MS Excel password; so if LOAD DATA INFILE does work, then the file isn't a password-protected MS Excel file

Comment: @MarkBaker PHPExcel I could convert the file but will that remove the password? I presume it is going to be an empty csv file. So, is there any way to add VBA - MACRO in my php file that would remove the password?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are working only on Excel files, I recommend using the PHPExcel module, [available here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) 
You can open password protected sheets since the 1.8.0 release I think

Comment: Sorry but, how in the earth can I open password protected excel with PHPExcel?